Issue using listofitems and tikz multipart shapes
This is just another case I keep running into of macros working fine if they just output text, but breaking things when used to output Tikz stuff. Is there a general solution to these kinds of problems? Why do some spots in tikz cause macro expansion to be extremely unusual?
Here is the specific issue I'm facing:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\tikzstyle{stack}=[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=#1,draw,anchor=center]

\newcommand{\stackof}[1]{%
    \readlist\elems{#1}
    \node[stack=\elemslen] {%
        \foreachitem\elem\in\elems{%
            % None of these work, due to \elemcnt undefined
            \iffalse
            \nodepart{\expandafter\numberstringnum\elemcnt{}} \elem%
            \expandafter\ifnum\elemcnt=1\nodepart{one}\fi% same issue
            \expandafter\ifnum\elemcnt=2\nodepart{two}\fi% same issue
            \expandafter\ifnum\elemcnt=3\nodepart{three}\fi% same issue
            \elem%
            \fi
            % but this works:
            \expandafter\numberstringnum\elemcnt{}: \elem%
            % and so does this:
            \expandafter\ifnum\elemcnt=1one:\fi% same issue
            \expandafter\ifnum\elemcnt=2two:\fi% same issue
            \expandafter\ifnum\elemcnt=3three:\fi% same issue
            \elem%
        }
    };
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \stackof{a,b,c}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

However, this is not the only time I've had these kinds of issues. Why do some macros seem to expand differently if the result of their expansion includes a Tikz/Pgf macro? What makes a macro that expands to hello different from one that expands to \nodepart{hello}?
I know that tikz does some extra parsing, but I don't understand how to work around it? Is there no "magic bullet" to expanding arbitrary LaTeX macros within a tikz environment?

there is no magic bullet to expanding arbitrary LaTeX macros in arbitrary other macros period. ;) off-topic, but don't use \tikzstyle. it's deprecated syntax. as a general rule, the most straightforward way to do things with tikz is to consider pgf/tikz methods first and to resort to other methods only where it is necessary or straightforward with significant benefits. so the obvious thing to do here would be to use \foreach, .list etc. but I suspect that is not the answer you want ;).

on-topic: how would I use .list or \foreach to traverse a comma-separated list and put each into subsequent \nodeparts? off-topic: what replaced \tikzstyle? is there a decent up-to-date guide on "new" tikz syntax; other than re-reading the great tome of pgf/tikz documentation?

well, the tutorials at the start of the manual should reflect current recommendations. you could also look at the revision history. \tikzset{} has replaced \tikzstyle. it should be straightforward to use \foreach to populate node parts. that is, I'd expect it to work though I don't remember trying. multipart nodes can be a bit flaky in my experience, but they can work well in the right situations.

note that if you use \foreach, you can get the count with just count=\elemcnt as one of the options. you can also set expansion of the list true if you need to (though generally you don't want this). I just think it is easier to go with the pgf/tikz 'way' when using pgf/tikz. in some cases, it doesn't provide the kind of thing you need and that's different, but when it does, it's generally better to look there first and it definitely handles iterating through lists as this is a very common thing to want to do.
